# mkusb not working

Tags: mkusb

so i have MkuSB installed, i believe. i open the program via "show all applications", answered yes to the questions and enter my password. i am then faced with the error in the following image [image]

how do i fix this, im completely torn at this moment. im running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
if you need any further information, i will be happy to oblige. thank you!

Comment: ntfs-3g:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2017.3.23-2
  Version table:
     1:2017.3.23-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: should i have put that in the edits of the original question?

Comment: sorry, im extremely new to any of this. how would i go about doing that?

Comment: ah thank you, ill get back to you with my results!

Comment: tytytyty! youve been a blessing. any way to mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) uses the program `mkfs.ntfs` when it creates persistent live drives (and the `usbdata` partition). This program is in the package `ntfs-3g`, which is normally installed automatically in Ubuntu and the Ubuntu community flavours (it is packed with the standard systems as installed from the iso files).

I run Lubuntu and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and in both cases the package `ntfs-3g` is there. I don't know why it is not there in your system. Maybe you have uninstalled it, maybe the system was damaged somehow.

Please try to install `ntfs-3g` with the commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

in a terminal window.

Comment: It's installed in Kubuntu 18.04 as well while setting up the system.

Comment: i probably uninstalled it somehow, im completely new to ANY flavor of linux whatsoever.... thank you guys

Comment: @DPS, You will get used to Ubuntu gradually, and you are welcome to ask new questions, when you need help again :-)